# How can I get a value from a Java file to a jsp?

Tags: spring, jsp

I have a value that is calculated in the java file that I need to use in the .jsp and add it to the footer of a table. How can I do that?

Comment: What version of the servlet are you running? What are your tries yet?

Comment: Yes I tried. I also failed. Which is why I'm asking for help. Im on Tomcat 8.5.30 if that helps

Comment: Everything I tried had no results other than causing errors or other things not to load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add calculated value from java file to ModelAndView object like

```
      ModelAndView modalAndView=new ModelAndView();

      modalAndView.addObject("calculatedValue",calculatedValue);
```

and then extract it on jsp page using spring tag like :-

```
          ${calculatedValue}
```

Comment: Okay that makes a little sense, Im new to spring. So, I should use that call to the value when calling to get the data for the table?